# Running a Java function as an AWS Lambda function

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have created the following java class

```
  import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context; 

   public class SayHello implements RequestHandler<Request, Response> {

   public Response handleRequest(Request request, Context context) 
   {
       System.out.println("Running lambda function 123abc");
       return new Response("Lambda says hello");
   }
}
```

I have bundled this into a jar called myjar.jar and created a lambda function via my AWS console

[image]

I have selected Java 8 runtime, uploaded my jar so now stuck at what to do next.  I have created a Cloudwatch [image] event to be triggered by launch of an EC2 instance and added the target for this event as being my Lambda function. So what next?  Specifically the message "This function contains external libraries. Uploading a new file will override these libraries." puzzles me.
I just want to get the lambda function to execute when the cloudwatch event happens.
Also ,  where can I see the output of a System.out.println command when I eventually get this to run?

Comment: What is the actual question/problem? That message is just a clear warning that ext libraries will be overridden every time, just ignore it for now and go ahead. Take a look at [Lambda docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-functions.html), i might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell Lambda what the name of your handler function is. In Java, you would indicate this in one of two ways:

1. as *package.class::method*, for example: `com.mycompany.HelloWorld::handleRequest`
2. as *package.class*, for example: `com.mycompany.HelloWorld`

It's not clear how Lambda infers the name of the handler method in #2 (for example if there were two handler methods). It may simply be looking for `handleRequest` or it may use reflection in some way.

Anything that your Lambda function outputs will be sent to CloudWatch Logs. You can get there from the Monitoring tab of your Lambda function (or you could simply open up the CloudWatch Logs console and navigate from there).